# `scipy.optimize` functions hang even with `maxiter=0`

Tags: optimization, scipy, logistic-regression

I am trying to train the MNIST data (which I downloaded from [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/c/digit-recognizer/download/train.csv)) with simple multi-class logistic regression, but the `scipy.optimize` functions hang.

Here's the code:

```py
import csv
from math import exp
from numpy import *
from scipy.optimize import fmin, fmin_cg, fmin_powell, fmin_bfgs

# Prepare the data

def getIiter(ifname):
    """
    Get the iterator from a csv file with filename ifname
    """
    ifile = open(ifname, 'r')
    iiter = csv.reader(ifile)
    iiter.__next__()
    return iiter

def parseRow(s):
    y = [int(x) for x in s]
    lab = y[0]
    z = y[1:]
    return (lab, z)

def getAllRows(ifname):
    iiter = getIiter(ifname)
    x = []
    l = []
    for row in iiter:
        lab, z = parseRow(row)
        x.append(z)
        l.append(lab)
    return x, l

def cutData(x, y):
    """
    70% training
    30% testing
    """
    m = len(x)
    t = int(m * .7)
    return [(x[:t], y[:t]), (x[t:], y[t:])]

def num2IndMat(l):
    t = array(l)
    tt = [vectorize(int)((t == i)) for i in range(10)]
    return array(tt).T

def readData(ifname):
    x, l = getAllRows(ifname)
    t = [[1] + y for y in x]
    return array(t), num2IndMat(l)

#Calculate the cost function

def sigmoid(x):
    return 1 / (1 + exp(-x))

vSigmoid = vectorize(sigmoid)
vLog = vectorize(log)

def costFunction(theta, x, y):
    sigxt = vSigmoid(dot(x, theta))
    cm = (- y * vLog(sigxt) - (1 - y) * vLog(1 - sigxt)) / m / N
    return sum(cm)

def unflatten(flatTheta):
    return [flatTheta[i * N : (i + 1) * N] for i in range(n + 1)]

def costFunctionFlatTheta(flatTheta):
    return costFunction(unflatten(flatTheta), trainX, trainY)

def costFunctionFlatTheta1(flatTheta):
    return costFunction(flatTheta.reshape(785, 10), trainX, trainY)

x, y = readData('train.csv')
[(trainX, trainY), (testX, testY)] = cutData(x, y)

m = len(trainX)
n = len(trainX[0]) - 1
N = len(trainY[0])

initTheta = zeros(((n + 1), N))
flatInitTheta = ndarray.flatten(initTheta)
flatInitTheta1 = initTheta.reshape(1, -1)
```

In the last two lines we flatten `initTheta` because the `fmin{,_cg,_bfgs,_powell}` functions seem to only take vectors as the initial value argument `x0`. I also flatten `initTheta` using `reshape` in hope [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45763229/4063224) can be of help.

There is no problem computing the cost function which takes up less than 2 seconds on my computer:

```
print(costFunctionFlatTheta(flatInitTheta), costFunctionFlatTheta1(flatInitTheta1))
# 0.69314718056 0.69314718056
```

But all the `fmin` functions hang, even if I set `maxiter=0`.
e.g.

```
newFlatTheta = fmin(costFunctionFlatTheta, flatInitTheta, maxiter=0)
```

or

```
newFlatTheta1 = fmin(costFunctionFlatTheta1, flatInitTheta1, maxiter=0)
```

When I interrupt the program, it seems to me it all hangs at lines in `optimize.py` calling the cost functions, lines like this:

```
return function(*(wrapper_args + args))
```

For example, if I use `fmin_cg`, this would be line 292 in `optimize.py` (Version 0.5).

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Never assume the input data is irrelevant to the problem :) Besides, you want to make it easy for people to help you. If one can simply copy&paste the code example to reproduce the problem and try new solutions you are much more likely to get a useful answer.

Comment: @kazemakase (My reply just disappeared for no apparent reason so I'm typing it again...) Thanks for the suggestions. I have added the bits of data-parsing code, and hopefully it is reproducible now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found a way to stop `fmin_cg` from hanging.

Basically I just need to write a function that computes the gradient of the cost function, and pass it to the `fprime` parameter of `fmin_cg`.

```
def gradient(theta, x, y):
    return dot(x.T, vSigmoid(dot(x, theta)) - y) / m / N

def gradientFlatTheta(flatTheta):
    return ndarray.flatten(gradient(flatTheta.reshape(785, 10), trainX, trainY))
```

Then

```
newFlatTheta = fmin_cg(costFunctionFlatTheta, flatInitTheta, fprime=gradientFlatTheta, maxiter=0)
```

terminates within seconds, and setting `maxiter` to a higher number (say 100) one can train the model within reasonable amount of time.

[The documentation of `fmin_cg`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin_cg.html#scipy.optimize.fmin_cg) says the gradient would be numerically computed if no `fprime` is given, which is what I suspect caused the hanging.

Thanks to [this notebook by zgo2016@Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/zgo2016/digit-recognizer-one-vs-all) which helped me find the solution.